# Shouldn't the symbol for "There is no..." be "$\neg\forall$" instead of "$\neg\exists$"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Currently following discrete math, and I came across quantifiers.

> If there's a predicate that phrases similar to "There is no..." (for example, "There is no human that can fly"), then shouldn't the expression using quantifiers use "$\neg\forall$" instead of "$\neg\exists$"?

It seems to me that both should be correct, although I am clearly wrong.

Comment: The first means "it is not true that all humans can fly".  The second means that "it is not true that there  exists a human who can fly."

Comment: $\neg\forall$ quite literally means "not every", and the statement "Not every human can fly" clearly carries different meaning to your intended "There is no human that can fly."

Comment: It’s more a problem with English grammar that postpones the negation. In French it would be il n’y a aucun*, in Italian *non c’è alcuno*.

Comment: "There is no angel" means that "Angels do not exist". Thus : $\lnot \exists x \text {Angel}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the difference between these two statements:
$$\lnot\forall x\in\mathbf{R}(x^2>0)$$
$$\lnot\exists x\in\mathbf{R}(x^2>0)$$
The first way to understand the difference between $\lnot\forall$ and $\lnot\exists$ is to read directly what these statements mean. The first statement is equivalent to "it is not true that for all real $x$ that $x^2$ is greater than zero. This is clearly true, since $0^2=0$. On the other hand, the second statement means that "it is not true that there exists a real $x$ such that $x^2>0$". But every $x$ other than $0$ fulfills this requirement, so this statement is certainly false.

The second way is to use De Morgan's laws:
$$\exists x\in\mathbf{R}(x^2\leq0)$$
$$\forall x\in\mathbf{R}(x^2\leq0)$$

We can easily see now not only that the statements are not equivalent but also which ones are true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are very different.

There is no human who can fly means $\neg\exists x [f(x)]$ or if one explicitly refers to humans $\neg\exists x[ h(x)\wedge f(x)]$.

The statement $\neg \forall x[f(x)]$ or more explicitly referring to humans, $\neg \forall x[h(x)\Rightarrow f(x)]$, means that it is not true that all humans can fly.